# Peewee ForeignKeyField as BigIntegerField

Tags: python, mysql-python, peewee

From the Peewee [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#field-types-table), it appears that a `ForeignKeyField` is stored as an integer across all DBs, including MySQL which is what I'm using. Unfortunately, the key I'm trying to reference has to be a `BigIntegerField` (It's a 12-digit number).

Is it possible to force a `ForeignKeyField` to be `BigIntegerField`? I can't find any reference to it in the docs. Has anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peewee will use the same storage-type for a foreign-key as the primary-key it references.

So you would just want to make sure the field you're referring to is using either `BigAutoField` (auto-increment) or `BigIntegerField`.

Comment: Thank you! I went into the code and couldn't quite tell if it was doing it. Clearly my "it works in SQLite but not in MySQL" problem is from another source.